# Regular expression to split string based on pattern

Tags: java, regex, string

I would like someone to help me to rectify my regular expression to split this string:

```
{constraint.null.invalid}{0,1,2}
```

Basically, I want anything inside `{` and `}`, so my output must be:

- `constraint.null.invalid`
- `0,1,2`.

My regular expression, which I've tried closely is:

```
\{([\S]+)\}
```

But the value I get is:

```
constraint.null.invalid}{0,1,2
```

What am I missing?

Sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{([\\S]+)\\}", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    String test = "{constraint.null.invalid}{0,1,2}";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

Thanks

---

PS: The string can contain values bounded by 1 or more `{` and `}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` quantifier is greedy. Use `+?` for the reluctant version.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html for details.

Answer (score 2):

a little different approach, with this pattern "\{([^\{\}]*)\}"

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ReTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "bla bla {constraint.null.invalid} bla bla bla {0,1,2} bla bla";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{([^\\{\\}]*)\\}");

        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

        while (m.find()){
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```